# auto confirm users Cognito + Node JS

Tags: node.js, api, amazon-cognito

I trying to auto confirm my users in cognito + node Js app.
I tried this code as a Util, and here inside the function; and cant make it work

I try to go to aws documentation but the code is ambiguous and doesn't explain to much.

here is my code:

```
userPool.signUp(req.body.email, req.body.password, attributeList, 
null, function (err, result) {
  event = {
    request: {
      "userAttributes": {
        "email": req.body.email
      },
      "validationData": {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": req.body.email
      }
    },
    response: { 
      autoVerifyEmail: true
    }
  }
  // Confirm the user

  // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
  if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
      event.response.autoVerifyEmail = 'true';
  }

  // Return to Amazon Cognito
  callback(null, event);

if (err) {
  console.log("Error aws: ", err.message);
  // return;
}
cognitoUser = result.user;
console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
next();
// return;
});
}
```

can anyone help me to say, what Im doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the signup callback you should call AdminConfirmSignUp. the syntax is given below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminConfirmSignUp.html

```js
userPool.signUp(req.body.email, req.body.password, attributeList,
    null, function (err, result) {
        event = {
            request: {
                "userAttributes": {
                    "email": req.body.email
                },
                "validationData": {
                    "Name": "email",
                    "Value": req.body.email
                }
            },
            response: {
                autoVerifyEmail: true
            }
        }
        // Confirm the user

        var confirmParams = {
            UserPoolId: 'provide your user pool id', /* required */
            Username: req.body.email /* required */
          };
          cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminConfirmSignUp(confirmParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred

           
            // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
            if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
                event.response.autoVerifyEmail = 'true';
            }

            // Return to Amazon Cognito
            callback(null, event);

            if (err) {
                console.log("Error aws: ", err.message);
                // return;
            }
            cognitoUser = result.user;
            console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
            next();
            // return;
          });

    });
 }
```

Comment: I try it, but the codes tell me cognitoidentityserviceprovider is not defined; I use my UserPool, new AmazonCognitoIdentity.adminConfirmSignUp and any works;

Comment: add following code ..

var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

Comment: i set that variable and first told me "missing region in config" and add this: AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
then told me missing config and add this:
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: mypoolid
});

and still not working

Comment: can you share your code file? removing all the confidential code? i.e. user pool info etc?

Comment: https://github.com/luishdez87/signupAWS/tree-save/master/awsSignUp.js

this is the file

Comment: just look the changes which i have proposed it should work fine

Comment: here is the file

Comment: There isn’t anything to compare.
luishdez87:master and asadmakram:master are identical.

maybe your changes were not commited

Comment: can you see now?

Comment: yes, still have the error:
Missing credentials in config